# Woocomerce Edit source code of form in wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am new to WordPress I have a form using Woocommerce plugin  I would like to edit it and add additional functions I check the WordPress platform but I could find where to edit it

Comment: You need to consult the WooCommerce developer documentation. It’s usually more complicated than just opening up some code and editing it. Note that third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: @jacob Do you have some useful links so I can check them thanks

Comment: You can check the WooCommerce documentation here: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=woocommerce+documentation